# Apache: dynamically interpret static files

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

This is a very specific question, but a good answer might also give me better understanding of Apache request processing.

I have a python script to generate a HTML page. The script is called by means of the following apache config item:

```
 WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^.*\.mako$ /usr/local/lib/cgi-bin/myscript.py
```

But I would rather use `.mako` files just the way `.php` files are commonly used. That, is for a request matching `^.*\.mako$`, the script should only be called when there is a file on the server which would be served by apache itself if the config item was not there.
And I would also access that file in the python script.

Is that at all possible? I don't want to use ugly hacks trying to deduce a filename in the python script from the Request URI (which indeed is handled over wsgi).

UPDATE:

Thanks for the very nice solution! I thought I'd publish my final setup because it seems many have search for something similarly flexible. What I want is a very *mixed* environment, that is, I want to have static and dynamic content in the same directories to ease editing. Also, we must be able to access dynamic content as a fallback *transparently*. E.g. Request for `http://someserver/file.html`, but there is no physical `/var/www/file.html` file, then produce it dynamically using the existing `/var/www/file.html.mako`.

apache.conf:

```
# Disable MultiViews, it will get in your way!

# if resource.html doesn't exist, but resource.html.mako does,
# then use that
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME}.mako -f
RewriteRule (.*\.html) $1.mako

# Make .mako files dynamically interpreted by /usr/.../mako-handler.py
AddHandler x-application/mako-template .mako
Action     x-application/mako-template /mako-handler
WSGIScriptAlias /mako-handler /usr/.../mako-handler.py
```

mako-handler.py:

```
...
physical_template_filepath = environ['PATH_TRANSLATED']
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
AddHandler x-application/mako-template .mako
Action x-application/mako-template /mako-handler
WSGIScriptAlias /mako-handler /usr/local/lib/cgi-bin/myscript.py
```

The sequence is that .mako extension will be mapped to mime type of 'x-application/mako-template'. That mime type is then mapped to URL '/mako-handler' and that URL is then mapped to the WSGI script.

Comment: Insane. Exactly what I've been looking for for hours! What I can add is that the script get the physical filename corresponding to the request in the `PATH_TRANSLATED` variable (no matter if CGI or WSGI). This isn't the case when you don't use `Action`